# underscore template adding extra <h2> tags

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have this simple template:

```
  <script type="text/template" id="dashboard_tem">
    <h2>Dashboard<h2>
  </script>
```

I render it via:

```
    var tem = $('#dashboard_tem').html();
    this.$el.html(_.template(tem, {}));
```

However, `this.$el` html becomes:

```
<div>
    <h2>Dashboard</h2><h2></h2>
</div>
```

Notice the extra `<h2>` at the end. Why is that?

Comment: `<h2>Dashboard<h2>` => `<h2>Dashboard</h2>`

Comment: BTW, you get that result because you can't put an `<h2>` inside an `<h2>` so the browser closes the first `<h2>` before opening the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have your h2 closed before setting it as the variable tem:

```
<script type="text/template" id="dashboard_tem">
  <h2>Dashboard<h2>
</script>
```

change to

```
<script type="text/template" id="dashboard_tem">
  <h2>Dashboard</h2>
</script>
```